# Render pdf with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf

In my project, I want to somehow display a pdf file on the page. For this, I am trying to use the `<object>` tag. So far, so good, since the pdf lives in the `/public` folder in my Rails app.

The problem is that now I want the user to be able to display a pdf that is on his pc. I tried using Javascript to alter the `<object>` tag, but that does not work since Rails generates a new GET request to get the file, and the file is not on the server. Any ideas of how I can solve this?

I have tried using PDF.js, but it does not integrate well in the assets pipeline. Also, I would have to customize and hack the code to add some other functionalities, so PDF.js is kinda off the table (at least for now).

Comment: I don't think you can display a file from user machine on a website, why would you do that?

Comment: I don't wanna display the user's pdf on the website. What I want is what PDF.js does: it's kinda a pdf reader embedded on the page. The file is not sent to the server.

Comment: Exactly, and what I'm saying that is either is already or will be impossible with most browsers in nearest future.

Comment: Why do you say that? Friggin PDF.js already does that! The only reasons I'm not using is that I would have to put it in an `<iframe>` and I would also have to add custom code to it so I can save the name of the pdf. I think it is totally possible, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wicked_pdf gem to generate pdf then use Google PDF viewer for displaying it

Comment: The pdf is already generated. I won't generate it from the models or whatever. My intention is to have a pdf reader on the web page, and this reader should be able to read local files (of course, without sending them to the server).